# Construct a Ladder

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, array

## Introduction

I want to build a ladder.
For this, I have scavenged from the junkyard two long boards with holes in them, and I want to place the steps into these holes.
However, the holes are not evenly placed, so the steps will be a little wonky, and I find it hard to estimate the amount of rod I need for them.
Your job is to do the calculations for me.

## Input

Your input is two bit vectors, given as arrays of integers, which represent the two boards.
A `0` represents a segment of one aud (*arbitrary unit of distance*) without a hole, and a `1` represents a segment of one aud with a single hole.
The arrays may be of different lengths and contain a different number of `1`s, but they will not be empty.

I will construct my ladder as follows.
First, I place the two boards exactly one aud apart, and align their left ends.
For each index `i`, I measure the distance between the `i`th hole of the first board with the `i`th hole of the second board, cut a piece of rod, and attach it between the two holes.
I stop once I run out of holes in one of the boards.

## Output

Your output is the total amount of rod I'll need for the steps, measured in auds.
The output should be correct to at least six significant digits.

## Example

Consider the inputs `[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0]` and `[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]`.
The resulting ladder looks like this:

[image: A really funky ladder.]

The total length of the rod in this ladder is `7.06449510224598` auds.

## Rules

You can write either a function or a full program.
The lowest byte count wins, and standard loopholes are disallowed.

## Test Cases

```
[0] [0] -> 0.0
[0] [1,0] -> 0.0
[1,0,0] [1,1,1,1,1] -> 1.0
[0,1,0,1] [1,0,0,1] -> 2.414213562373095
[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0] [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1] -> 7.06449510224598
[1,1,1,1,1] [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1] -> 12.733433128760744
[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0] [0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1] -> 20.38177416534678
```

Comment: For your own safety, I really don't recommend climbing any ladder that looks like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## J, 20 bytes

```
4+/@:o.(<0 1)|:-/&I.
```

It uses the trick in [MickyT's answer in R](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47280/9288).

`(<0 1)|:` gives the diagonal of a matrix. For the explanations of the other parts, see [FUZxxl's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47282/9288).

Comment: Neat. I admit defeat.

Answer (score 10):

### J, 22 characters

Not inspired by the answer of randomra. The `I.` part is equal as that is the immediately obvious way of finding the holes.

```
(4+/@:o.<.&#$-/@,:)&I.
```

- `I. y` – all the indices of `y` repeated as often as the corresponding item of `y`. Incidentally, if `y` is a vector of booleans, `I. y` contains the indices at which `y` is `1`. For instance, `I. 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1` yields `0 3 4 5 8`.
- `x u&v y` – the same as `(v x) u (v y)`. Applied as `x u&I. y`, we get `(I. x) u (I. y)`. Let's continue with the transformed input.
- `x <.&# y` – the lesser of the lengths of `x` and `y`.
- `x -/@,: y` – the difference of the items of `x` and `y`. If one vector is longer, it is padded with zeroes.
- `x $ y` – `y` reshaped to the shape specified by `x`. Specifically, if `x` is a scalar, `x` elements are taken from `y`. In this usage, `x (<.&# $ -/@,:) y` makes sure that trailing holes are ignored.
- `4 o. y` – the function `%: 1 + *: y`, that is, sqrt(1 + *y*²). Incidentally, this function maps from hole distance to length of rods.
- `+/ y` – the sum of the elements of `y`.

Answer (score 10):

## Python, 85

```python
lambda*A:sum(abs(x-y+1j)for x,y in zip(*[[i for i,x in enumerate(l)if x]for l in A]))
```

This turned out similar to [Mac's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47281/20260). Convert the lists of 0's and 1's to ordered lists of the one-indices, and then sum the distance between respective elements.

Comment: Nicely done. Nice trick with the complex literal!

Comment: I'm a bit sad that this is one byte shorter than my [other answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47284/20260), which I think is a more creative solution.

Answer (score 6):

## J, <s>32</s> 28 bytes

The verb `I.` returns the positions of `1`s in a binary string which is a huge help.

```
   +/@,@(=/&(#\)*[:>:&.*:-/)&I.

   0 1 0 1 (+/@,@(=/&(#\)*[:>:&.*:-/)&I.) 1 0 0 1
2.41421
```

For a better J solution check [FUZxxl's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47282/7311).

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, <strike>77</strike> 73 bytes

```js
r x=[a|(a,1)<-zip[1..]x]
i#j=sum$zipWith(\n m->sqrt((n-m)**2+1))(r i)$r j
```

Usage: `[0,1,0,1] # [1,0,0,1]` which outputs `2.414213562373095`

How it works: the function `r` returns a list of the positions of the holes of a board, e.g. `r [0,1,0,1]` -> `[2,4]`. `#` zips two of those lists and turns it into a list of distances between corresponding holes and finally sums it.

Answer (score 5):

## R, 67

Uses outer to do a difference for indexed holes.  Diag returns required differences.
Then sum the calculated distances

```
function(a,b)sum((diag(outer(which(a==1),which(b==1),"-"))^2+1)^.5)
```

[Test run](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=KEeVlJ6h) in R Fiddle.  I have wrapped it in a print to show the return complies with spec.

```
> print((function(a,b)sum((diag(outer(which(a==1),which(b==1),"-"))^2+1)^.5))(c(0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0),c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1)),digits=10)
[1] 7.064495102
> print((function(a,b)sum((diag(outer(which(a==1),which(b==1),"-"))^2+1)^.5))(c(1,1,1,1,1),c(0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1)),digits=10)
[1] 12.73343313
>
```

Comment: Nice one. `a==1` can be `a>0` or `!!a`.

Answer (score 4):

## CJam, <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```
l~]{:L,{L=},}%z{,(},0\{~-_*)mq+}/
```

Very naive approach... it expects the input as CJam-style arrays on STDIN

```
[0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0] [1 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1]
```

[Here is a test harness](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=qN%2F%7B%22-%3E%22%2F0%3D'%2CSer~%0A%0A%5D%7B%3AL%2C%7BL%3D%7D%2C%7D%25z%7B%2C(%7D%2C0%5C%7B~-_*)mq%2B%7D%2F%0A%0Ap%7D%2F&input=%5B0%5D%20%5B0%5D%20-%3E%200.0%0A%5B0%5D%20%5B1%2C0%5D%20-%3E%200.0%0A%5B1%2C0%2C0%5D%20%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%20-%3E%201.0%0A%5B0%2C1%2C0%2C1%5D%20%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%20-%3E%202.414213562373095%0A%5B0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%5D%20%5B1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%20-%3E%207.06449510224598%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C1%5D%20%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%20-%3E%2012.733433128760744%0A%5B0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C0%5D%20%5B0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C1%2C1%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1%5D%20-%3E%2020.38177416534678) for all the example inputs. The results in the input field are used before the actual code is called. You can remove them if you don't trust me. ;)

### Explanation

```
l~]                               "Read and eval input, wrap in an array.";
   {        }%                    "Map this block onto both input arrays.";
    :L,                           "Store array in L, get its length N.";
       {L=},                      "In the range [0 .. N-1] get all elements where L is 1.";
                                  "At this point we've converted each array into a list of its
                                   non-zero indices.";
              z                   "Transpose the array, pairing up indices at the same position.";
               {,(},              "Filter the extraneous elements of the longer input.";
                    0\            "Put a 0 before the array.";
                      {        }/ "For each pair of holes...";
                       ~-         "Unwrap the pair, take the difference.";
                         _*)mq    "Square, increment, square root.";
                              +   "Add to the running total.";
```

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <strike>105</strike> <strike>102</strike> 100 bytes

```
i=lambda l:(i for i,h in enumerate(l)if h)
l=lambda*a:sum(((a-b)**2+1)**.5for a,b in zip(*map(i,a)))
```

Pretty basic, just converts the input lists to lists of hole indices, then computes distance between each pair of such indices.

Test case:

```
>>> print l([0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1])
7.06449510225
```

Credit to @FryAmTheEggman for a couple of byte-saving suggestions. Turns out this can be golfed further, as demonstrated in [xnor's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47285/38252).

Comment: You can remove the spaces after `enumerate(l)` and the `0.5` (which could just be .5).

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman: absolutely right, thanks! Changed as suggested.

Comment: Found another thing using starred assignment: `l=lambda*a:sum(((a-b)**2+1)**.5for a,b in zip(*map(i,a)))`

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman: thanks again! Unfortunately it seems xnor's [gone one better](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47285/38252) though - much the same, but with the first lambda rolled into the second as a list comprehension...

Answer (score 4):

## Python, 86

```python
f=lambda a,b,i=1j:a>[]<b and a[0]*b[0]*abs(i)+f(a[a[:1]<=b:],b[b[:1]<=a:],i+a[0]-b[0])
```

A low-level and naive recursive solution without any list searching.

The input lists are `a` and `b`. If either is empty, return `0`.

Otherwise, let `x` and `y` be their first elements (the code doesn't actually assign these because you can't do assignments in a `lambda`, but it will make explaining easier). If both are 1, i.e. their product is 1, then they contribute rod distance. We keep track of distance in the complex number `i`, so that distance is the absolute value. Actually, we compute it regardless, then multiply it by `x*y`.

Then, we recurse. The idea is to shift both lists one step, unless one list starts with a 0 and the other with a one, in which case we shift only the 0 list. That way, 1's are always consumed in pairs. We could check these conditions with `x<y` and `y<x`, but it's shorter to take advantage of list comparison as `a[:1]<=b`. Finally, we adjust the complex displacement between the current elements by `x-y`.

Comment: Since you're upset that this was 1 byte more than your other solution, I found a way to save a byte. Change `a>[]<b` to `a>0<b`. It works since both `[]` and `0` are falsy, so they're equivalent.

Comment: Also, what is `a:`?

Comment: @mbomb007. Did you do any testing? In python2: `([] > []) != ([] > 0)`, and in python3 it is an error (unorderable types).

Comment: @mbomb007. The `a:` is part of the slice `[b[:1]<=a:]`.

Answer (score 3):

## Pyth, 30 bytes

```
s+0m^h^-hded2 .5CmfTm*hb@kblkQ
```

Try it [online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/) with the input `[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0], [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]`.

#### Explanation:

I convert the lists into lists of indices `[2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8]` and `[1, 4, 5, 6, 9]` and zip them together `[(2,1), (3,4), (5,5), (6,6), (7,9)]`. Then I subtract the values, square them, add 1 and sum over all square roots.

```
CmfTm*hb@kblkQ
 m           Q     map each list k in input() to the following list:
    m      lk         map each value b of [0, 1, 2, ..., len(k)-1] to the value:
     *hb@kb              (b + 1) * k[b]
  fT                  filter the list for positive values
C                  zip these two resulting lists

s+0m^h^-hded2 .5...
   m            ...  map each pair of values d to: 
    ^h^-hded2 .5         ((d[0] - d[1])^2 + 1)^0.5
 +0                  insert 0 at the front of the list
s                    sum
```

Shame that `sum` doesn't work for empty lists.

Answer (score 3):

## [Clip 3](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Clip), <s>55 47</s> 38

```
[cr+`j[v[w#)#mvw2B}}(c)c]sl`{%ky1%kx1`
```

For the list with the fewer holes, the program iterates through it, and connects each hole with the corresponding hole of the other list. The sizes are calculated and summed.

```
>java -jar Clip3.jar ladder.clip
{0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0}
{1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1}
7.064495102245980096000721459859050810337066650390625
```

### Explanation

```
[c          .- Assign c to the lists, in order of size    -.
  r+`       .- The sum of...                              -.
   j[v[w    .- Join the lists with a function on v, w     -.
     #      .- Square root                                -.
      )     .- 1 plus                                     -.
       #    .- The square of                              -.
        mvw .- The distance between v and w               -.
       2
     B      .- (one-half, so #...B means square root)     -.
   }}(c)c   .- Apply joining function to the lists        -.
  ]sl`{     .- c is the (sorted by size) list of...       -.
    %ky1    .- Indices of y (the second input) which are 1-.
    %kx1    .- Indices of x (the first input) which are 1 -.
  `
```

If we are very liberal about the input format, we can reduce this to 36 bytes by removing each `k`. This requires the input to be a string of the control characters characters `\0` and `\1`.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>116</s> 115 bytes

This is a recursive solution.

It became pretty annoying when I found that `index()` just throws an error when no value is found, but I made it work. Unfortunately, I cannot use a lambda. It also annoyed me that `list.remove()` doesn't return the list, but instead returns `None`.

```python
def f(x,y,r=0):
    try:i,j=x.index(1),y.index(1)
    except:return r
    x.pop(i);y.pop(j);return f(x,y,r+((i-j)**2+1)**.5)
```

Run online here: http://repl.it/c5L/2

Comment: Even with tabs, that code is 116 bytes, not 112.

Comment: Ah, missed the newlines, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

## ECMAScript 6, 86 bytes

This originally started out using reduce (I wanted to see if it could be done in one loop as opposed to @edc65 answer).

```
f=(c,b,a=[0,...c],j)=>a.reduce((c,v,i)=>c+=v&&(j=b.indexOf(1,j)+1,v=i-j,j)?Math.sqrt(1+v*v):0)
```

But using @edc65 for `map` and `&&t` to return the value I was able to shorten it quite a bit.

```
f=(a,b,j,c=0)=>a.map((v,i)=>c+=v&&(j=b.indexOf(1,j)+1,v=i+1-j,j)&&Math.sqrt(1+v*v))&&c

f=(a,b,j,c=0)        //variables note the j can be undefined
=>a.map((v,i)=>      //loop through the first array
c+=                  //add 
v&&                  //test to see if we have a hole
(j=b.indexOf(1,j)+1, //if so see if there is a whole on the other board
v=i+1-j,             //calculate index difference
j)                   //the last var gets evaluated so check to see if indexOf returned -1
&&Math.sqrt(1+v*v))  //calculate 
&&c                  //return sum
```

Comment: I still have to find a single case when reduce beats map with an user managed accumulator.

Comment: @edc65 probably true, `reduce` makes more sense semantically, but other than that it is actually kind of awkward to use. Of course, since when did code golfers worry about semantics.

Answer (score 2):

## Java, 151

This just walks along `a` looking for ones, then walks along `b` when it finds one. If `float` accuracy is acceptable I could save a couple bytes, but I went with `double` to match the test output.

```java
double d(int[]a,int[]b){double z=0;for(int x=-1,y=0,d=b.length;x++<a.length&y<d;z+=a[x]>0?Math.sqrt((y-x)*(y++-x)+1):0)for(;y<d&&b[y]<1;y++);return z;}
```

With whitespace:

```java
double d(int[]a,int[]b){
    double z=0;
    for(int x=-1,y=0,d=b.length;
            x++<a.length&y<d;
            z+=a[x]>0?Math.sqrt((y-x)*(y++-x)+1):0)
        for(;y<d&&b[y]<1;y++);
    return z;
}
```

Comment: Six significant digits is enough accuracy, so it float gives you that, go for it.

Comment: @Zgarb The repeated additions on most inputs only give me 4-5 digits tops, so I'll stick to the more accurate version. Thanks for the clarification, though.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) 108

The main point is the f function that maps the input 0..1 arrays in arrays of holes positions. Then the arrays are scanned computing a total rods length using the pythagorean theorem. The `|0` near the end is needed to convert NaNs that can result when the driver array (the first) is longer than the second.

```js
F=(a,b,f=a=>a.map(v=>++u*v,u=0).filter(x=>x))=>
  f(a,b=f(b)).map((v,i)=>t+=Math.sqrt((w=b[i]-v)*w+1|0),t=0)&&t
```

**Test** In Firefox / FireBug console

```
;[[[0],[0]]
 ,[[0],[1,0]]
 ,[[1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,1]]
 ,[[0,1,0,1],[1,0,0,1]]
 ,[[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1]]
 ,[[1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1]]
 ,[[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1]]]
.forEach(v=>console.log('['+v[0]+']','['+v[1]+']',F(...v)))
```

> [0] [0] 0
> [0] [1,0] 0
> [1,0,0] [1,1,1,1,1] 1
> [0,1,0,1] [1,0,0,1] 2.414213562373095
> [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0] [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1] 7.06449510224598
> [1,1,1,1,1] [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1] 12.733433128760744
> [0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0]   [0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1] 20.38177416534678

Answer (score 1):

## Octave, <s>60</s> <s>59</s> 42

```
@(a,b)trace(sqrt((find(a)'-find(b)).^2+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 98

```
sub l{$r=0;@a=grep$a->[$_],0..$#$a;@b=grep$b->[$_],0..$#$b;$r+=sqrt 1+(shift(@a)-shift@b)**2 while@a&&@b;$r}
```

### Readable:

```
sub l {
    $r = 0;
    @a = grep $a->[$_], 0 .. $#$a;
    @b = grep $b->[$_], 0 .. $#$b;
    $r += sqrt 1 + (shift(@a) - shift @b) ** 2 while @a && @b;
    $r
}
```

### Testing:

```
use Test::More;
for (<DATA>) {
    my ($A, $B, $r) = /\[ ([0-9,]+) \] \s \[ ([0-9,]+) \] \s -> \s ([0-9.]+) /x;
    $a = [split /,/, $A];
    $b = [split /,/, $B];
    cmp_ok l(), '==', $r, "test $_";
}
done_testing($.);
__DATA__
[0] [0] -> 0.0
[0] [1,0] -> 0.0
[1,0,0] [1,1,1,1,1] -> 1.0
[0,1,0,1] [1,0,0,1] -> 2.414213562373095
[0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,0] [1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1] -> 7.06449510224598
[1,1,1,1,1] [0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,1] -> 12.733433128760744
[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0] [0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1] -> 20.38177416534678
```

Answer (score 0):

### APL, <s>35</s> 28 bytes

Uses a similar algorithm to the J solution, but APL has fewer builtins.

```
{+/4○⊃-/{⍵⍴¨⍨⌊/⍴¨⍵}⍵/¨⍳¨⍴¨⍵}
```

Example input:

```
      {+/4○⊃-/{⍵⍴¨⍨⌊/⍴¨⍵}⍵/¨⍳¨⍴¨⍵}(1 0 0 1)(0 1 0 1)
2.414213562
```